# Remove text block from lot of TXT files

Tags: xml, powershell

I need some help on this:

My code remove a peace o text from a lot of txt files on a diretory.
I remove de content from file, but it is save the same content in all files.I can remove the text, but when save de file, it  save the first file content in all next files.

This is the removed block: (Working)

```
    <opex:OPEXMetadata xmlns:opex="http://www.openpreservationexchange.org/opex/v1.0">
    <opex:Transfer>
      <opex:SourceID>9880a11c-a13e-4df3-a52d-8be0f7d7a4ab</opex:SourceID>
   </opex:Transfer>
   <opex:Properties>
     <opex:Title>Fakamae_2018005_KM</opex:Title>
     <opex:Description>Fakamae_2018005_KM</opex:Description>
     <opex:SecurityDescriptor>S_SubscriberAccess</opex:SecurityDescriptor>
     <opex:Identifiers>
          <opex:Identifier type="code">Fakamae_2018005_KM</opex:Identifier>
     </opex:Identifiers>
 </opex:Properties>
<opex:DescriptiveMetadata>
    <LegacyXIP xmlns="http://preservica.com/LegacyXIP">
        <AccessionRef>88158870-ba1a-44a1-ad70-5cc898a5b436</AccessionRef>
        <AccumulationRef>3b955682-e827-43bb-a446-2dd635f01ef0</AccumulationRef>
        </LegacyXIP>
    <ExtendedXIP xmlns="http://preservica.com/ExtendedXIP/v6.0">
        <DigitalSurrogate>false</DigitalSurrogate>
        <CoverageFrom>2019-09-21T00:00:00.000Z</CoverageFrom>
        <CoverageTo>2019-09-21T00:00:00.000Z</CoverageTo>
        </ExtendedXIP>
  <METATRANSCRIPT:METATRANSCRIPT xmlns:METATRANSCRIPT="http://www.mpi.nl/IMDI/Schema/IMDI"   xmlns="http://www.mpi.nl/IMDI/Schema/IMDI" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"  ArchiveHandle="hdl:2196/00-0000-0000-0013-5776-9" Date="2018-12-17" FormatId="IMDI 3.04" Originator="CMDI Maker by CLASS - Cologne Language Archive Services" Type="SESSION" Version="1.0" xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.mpi.nl/IMDI/Schema/IMDI http://www.mpi.nl/IMDI/Schema/IMDI_3.0.xsd">
    <Session>
        <Name>Fakamae_2018005_KM</Name>
        <Title>Samoana 1</Title>
        <Date>2018-05-11</Date>
        <Description LanguageId="ISO639-3:eng" Link="">A story about a boy, his grandmother, and a devil.  The boy makes a plan to steal the devil's pig. This text was recorded in video and archived files are in mp4 video format and wav audio format. The eaf ELAN file contains both English  and Bislama translations.</Description>

<METATRANSCRIPT:METATRANSCRIPT>
<opex:OPEXMetadata/>
```

This is what i need to Keep (Working)

```
 <METATRANSCRIPT:METATRANSCRIPT xmlns:METATRANSCRIPT="http://www.mpi.nl/IMDI/Schema/IMDI"   xmlns="http://www.mpi.nl/IMDI/Schema/IMDI" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"  ArchiveHandle="hdl:2196/00-0000-0000-0013-5776-9" Date="2018-12-17" FormatId="IMDI 3.04" Originator="CMDI Maker by CLASS - Cologne Language Archive Services" Type="SESSION" Version="1.0" xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.mpi.nl/IMDI/Schema/IMDI http://www.mpi.nl/IMDI/Schema/IMDI_3.0.xsd">
        <Session>
            <Name>Fakamae_2018005_KM</Name>
            <Title>Samoana 1</Title>
            <Date>2018-05-11</Date>
            <Description LanguageId="ISO639-3:eng" Link="">A story about a boy, his grandmother, and a devil.  The boy makes a plan to steal the devil's pig. This text was recorded in video and archived files are in mp4 video format and wav audio format. The eaf ELAN file contains both English  and Bislama translations.</Description>


<METATRANSCRIPT:METATRANSCRIPT>
```

But this content is save in all files

What am`i doing wrong?

```
 Get-ChildItem -Path 'C:\Source\' -Filter '*.xml' -File -Recurse |Rename-Item -NewName { $_.Name -replace '.xml','.txt' }



 ForEach-Object { Set-Content -Path C:\Source\* -Filter *.txt -Value  (Get-content -Path C:\Source\* -Filter *.txt | Select-String -Pattern 'opex:', 'ExtendedXIP','LegacyXIP','AccessionRef','AccumulationRef','DigitalSurrogate','CoverageFrom','CovergeTo' -NotMatch)}
```

Comment: is there a reason for not dealing with the data as XML? powershell can do that ...

Comment: Hi Lee,Yes it is, i have a lot of problems dealing with the data as xml. I`m newer on Powershell.

Comment: you are using `ForEach-Object` ... but not sending anything to it. then you are telling `Set-Content` to fill all the files with the output of `Get-Content` all files after they are ALL filtered by `Select-String`. ///// don't do that. [*grin*] start all over. do ONE step  for one  file. do the next step for that same one file, continue until you have that ONE file done. then wrap that in a loop to process ONE file at a time.