# PowerShell Adding

Tags: xml, powershell

I need your help on this please,

I m parsing another xml file, remove the nodes that i don t need, and save the same document, but it`s removes the xml declaration to.

Is there any way that don`t remove it? Or adding again?

I`ve got this litle xml file. But i need to add this declaration on this on the first line:

`<'?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?'>`

I tried a lot of ways, but or give -me error or an exception

```
<METATRANSCRIPT:METATRANSCRIPT xmlns:METATRANSCRIPT="http://www.mpi.nl/IMDI/Schema/IMDI" xmlns="http://www.mpi.nl/IMDI/Schema/IMDI" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" ArchiveHandle="hdl:2196/00-0000-0000-0013-5776-9" Date="2018-12-17" FormatId="IMDI 3.04" Originator="CMDI Maker by CLASS - Cologne Language Archive Services" Type="SESSION" Version="1.0" xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.mpi.nl/IMDI/Schema/IMDI http://www.mpi.nl/IMDI/Schema/IMDI_3.0.xsd">
   <Location>
     <Continent Link="http://www.mpi.nl/IMDI/Schema/Continents.xml"  Type="ClosedVocabulary">Oceania</Continent>
     <Country Link="http://www.mpi.nl/IMDI/Schema/Countries.xml"  Type="OpenVocabulary">Vanuatu</Country>
     <Region>Shefa Province</Region>
     <Address>Tongamea village Emae island</Address>
  </Location>
</METATRANSCRIPT:METATRANSCRIPT>
```

This is my code:

```
     [xml]$File = gc c:\\Source\Fakamae_2018005_KM.xml -Raw


     foreach ($meta in $File)
     {$File =($meta.xml,[xml]$File.GetElementsByTagName("METATRANSCRIPT:METATRANSCRIPT")[0].OuterXml)}
              $File.Save('c:\\Source\Output\Result.xml')
```

This is my error:

```
Cannot convert value "System.Object[]" to type "System.Xml.XmlDocument". Error: "The specified node cannot be inserted as the valid child of 
this node, because the specified node is the wrong type."
At line:9 char:10
+          $File =($meta.xml,[xml]$File.GetElementsByTagName("METATRANS ...
+          ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : MetadataError: (:) [], ArgumentTransformationMetadataException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : RuntimeException
```

Thanks a lot for any help.

Comment: Please post the errors/exceptions in full :)

Comment: [1] your $File` variable will be ONE item ... so there is nothing to iterate thru with `foreach`. [2] if you add that 1st single line to the lines in the 2nd set of lines, you get an invalid XML object. ///// what are you actually trying to do? the "why" is what i am wondering about ... [*grin*]

Comment: Thanks for your feedback Lee.

Comment: Thanks for your feedback Lee. [1] - I ve got a lot of xml files in one Directory "Source", that i need to remove some nodes. [2] - The METATRANSCRIPT:METATRANSCRIPT is what i need to keep, and that is what i  already got. [3] - The is, when a save the file without the nodes that i removed keeping the METATRANSCRIPT:METATRANSCRIPT node, my code remove also the '?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?'> xml declaration.[4] - On this case i ve got two options: or change my code to don`t remove the xml declaration or in the end i add it again (xml declaration).

Comment: For now, as you advise me before, i`m working just in one file at the time. But i will need to work with a lot of files inside a diretory and do the same process.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From your [earlier question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62070716/remove-text-block-from-lot-of-txt-files) I gather that you strip large xml files from all unwanted stuff and end up with only the `METATRANSCRIPT:METATRANSCRIPT` element.

On top of that you want to re-add the XML declaration.

Since you are treating the XML files as plain text to do the stripping, you can add the declaration like this:

```
Get-ChildItem -Path 'Path\To\XML\Files' -Filter '*.xml' -File | ForEach-Object {
    # do your routine on the xml in $_.FullName leaving only the METATRANSCRIPT element

    # if this leads to a string array in memory, just use that as-is
    $strippedXmlText = Strip-MyXml -Path $_.FullName

    # otherwise, if this leads to a temporary file, read it back in as string array:
    # $strippedXmlText = Get-Content -Path 'Path\To\The\Temp\File'

    $declaration = '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>'
    # rewrite that file by prepending the declaration line to it
    Set-Content -Path 'Path\To\The\Output\File' -Value $declaration, $strippedXmlText -Encoding UTF8
}
```